# The sequence for the generating function $\frac{x}{1-3x}$?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I'm using a book to try and learn generating functions; the concept is a bit confusing to me.

There is this example in the book, that, given $\sum_{n \geq 0}f_nx^n = \frac{x}{1-3x}$, find $f_n$, which is just a sequence of numbers, presumably integers since this is about combinatorics.

The book's solution is that $\frac{x}{1-3x}$ is basically $\sum_{n \geq 0}3^nx^n$, so """of course""" $f_n = 3^{n-1}$ due to the extra x. Here is the solution:

[image]

Yeah, of course. So I tried to do it myself and get the same answer. I started with

$$\sum_{n \geq 0}f_nx^n = \frac{x}{1-3x} = x\frac{1}{1-3x} = x\sum_{n \geq 0}3^nx^n =  \sum_{n \geq 0}3^nx^{n+1}$$

However, to reduce the value of $n$ in the sum, we have to increase the value of $n$ to start:

$$\sum_{n \geq 0}3^nx^{n+1} = \sum_{n \geq 1}3^{n-1}x^{n}$$

as

$$\sum_{n \geq 0}3^nx^{n+1} = x + 3x^2 + ...$$

but

$$\sum_{n \geq 0}3^{n-1}x^{n} = 1/3 + x + 3x^2 + ...$$

And this completely changes the formula, as $n\geq 1$ is different than $n\geq 0$.....right? Am I doing something wrong?

In fact, when I plug in $f_n = 3^{n-1}$ into $\sum_{n \geq 0}f_nx^n$, I get

$$ \sum_{n \geq 0}3^{n-1}x^n = \frac{1}{3}\sum_{n \geq 0}3^nx^n = \frac{1}{3}*\frac{1}{1-3x}$$

From the logic before, we can also get

$$\sum_{n \geq 0}3^{n-1}x^n = \frac{1}{3} + \sum_{n \geq 1}3^{n}x^{n+1} = x\frac{1}{1-3x} + \frac{1}{3}$$

....so what's the catch? I'm sure there is a good reason the book is saying what they're saying, and I must be either wrong or operating on a different set of assumptions. Can anyone who knows more about generating functions please tell me where I'm wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You just need to shift powers to account for the change in index.

Comment: I might be incredibly dense.....but didn't I do that (when I shifted n from 0 to 1, I also shifted the powers)??? I'm quite confused here XD

Comment: In your second line you get the coefficient of $x^n$ being $3^{n-1}$, which agrees with the book solution.  When you change the index back to $n=0$ of course you're getting a different function.  You did it right, then added a term to get it wrong, and now are confused that you're wrong (I think!).

Comment: Ok yeah I understand that, but the thing is that the $3^{n-1}$ sequence is based on a sum from $n\geq 1$, not $n\geq 0$. So if I plug the $3^{n-1}$ into the $f_n$ that starts at $n = 0$, I get a different answer. If the $f_n$ sum started at $n = 1$, there wouldn't be a problem, as the sum from $n\geq 1$ works. That's why, at least I think, I need to convert the sum from $n\geq 1$ to $n\geq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book is wrong because it claims that $f_0=1/3$ when in fact $f_0=0$.  The correct formula is
$$f_n=\begin{cases}3^{n-1}&\text{if $n>0$}\\0&\text{if $n=0$}\end{cases}$$